# Coded UI Test to read app.config value

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

Am new to c# as well as coded ui tests.
I have to do a coded ui test to validate a particular admin user login credentials. But the password should be read from app.config file.
How do i do this in coded ui recording and how does it playback?
Please advise.

Comment: there is no difference between Coded UI test and other C# application when you read config file.

Comment: Just watch out as you scale upwards since the app.config will be a part of the build and distributed to all your test agents (if you're using the LAB approach). This would mean all agents share the config - either a good thing or a bad thing.